# Elasticsearch queries in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana

I want to log all the queries made to Elasticsearch along with their response bodies in kibana.
Is there a way to do that?
I came to know a way to set. t he slowlogs threshold to 0 and log all the queries i slowlogs and then use filebeat to push those queries to kibana.
Is there any other way to do that

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not available atleast in basic and free version and even if you set search slowlog threshold to `0ms` it will just log the search query and other metadata of search query but wouldn't log the `search query response`.

It would be better to do this in your application which generated the search query and parse the response, then using filebeat you can send the application logs to Elasticsearch.